# How do I determine if a port is open on a Windows server?

Tags: windows-server-2003, port, ping

I'm trying to install a site under an alternative port on a server, but the port may be closed by a firewall. Is there a way to ping out or in, on a specific port, to see if it is open?

Comment: See also http://serverfault.com/questions/309357/ping-a-specific-port

Answer (score 799, accepted):

Assuming that it's a TCP (rather than UDP) port that you're trying to use:

1. On the server itself, use `netstat -an` to check to see which ports are listening.
2. From outside, just use `telnet host port` (or `telnet host:port` on Unix systems) to see if the connection is refused, accepted, or timeouts.

On that latter test, then in general:

- *connection refused* means that nothing is running on that port
- *accepted* means that something is running on that port
- *timeout* means that a firewall is blocking access

On Windows 7 or Windows Vista the default option 'telnet' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file. To solve this, just enable it: Click *Start** → **Control Panel** → *Programs* → *Turn Windows Features* on or off. In the list, scroll down and select *Telnet Client* and click <kbd>OK</kbd>.

Comment: In Win7 or Vista defaul option 'telnet' is not recognized as an internal or external command,operable program or batch file. To solve this, just enable it : Click Start, Control Panel, Programs, and then Turn Windows Features on or off. In the list, scroll down and select Telnet Client and click OK

Comment: @volody any suggestion on how do that w/o admin rights?

Comment: @PankajKohli use [PuTTy](http://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/~sgtatham/putty/download.html) telnet client instead.  It does not need to be installed.

Comment: What does `Could not open connection to the host, on port *x*: Connect failed` indicate?

Comment: The proper syntax for mine is "telnet host port", if it connects your screen will go black or have some gibberish reply.

Comment: @Alnitak I just wanted to check as I think this already answers my question. When I do `telnet api-3t.sandbox.paypal.com 443` I get `Connecting to api-3t.sandbox.paypal.com...Could not open connection to the host on port 443: Connect failed` Is this because the firewall is blocking it?

Comment: there is a difference if you open telnet.exe and then type `o host port` vs open command line (cmd.exe) and then type `telnet host port`

Comment: "connection timed out = firewall is blocking access" but whose firewall the source(outside 
 pc) or the destination's( the PC i am tring to telnet) ?

Comment: what about udp?

Comment: @DmitrySurin UDP is way harder, and depends on whether the far end is configured to send ICMP "destination unreachable" messages, and on the near end process having sufficient privilege to be able to receive those.

Answer (score 243):

On Windows you can use

```
netstat -na | findstr "your_port"
```

to narrow down the results. You can also filter for `LISTENING`, `ESTABLISHED`, `TCP` and such. Mind it's case-sensitive though.

Comment: you cant use find like this, it will be searching for files, you should use grep

Comment: @MoatazElmasry, that's true on Linux, but this is on a Windows server, where find is the correct command. Grep is not available on Windows. I just ran the exact command mentioned here, and it worked perfectly.

Comment: You can also run: netstat -an | select-string -pattern "your_port"

Comment: When I used that command i.e netstat -an | find "19345" , I didnt get any result. what does it mean?

Comment: `find` did not work in Windows 10 for me, but `netstat -na | findstr "8080"` worked

Comment: nothing happens, not with find or findstr

Comment: This works on Windows 10 as well, they have brought piping and `find` to Windows

Comment: `| findstr ":8080"`

Comment: "*You can also filter for LISTENING, ESTABLISHED, TCP and such*" How? What does this look like?

Answer (score 137):

If you're checking from the outside, not from the server itself, and you don't want to bother installing telnet (as it doesn't come with the last versions of Windows) or any other software, then you have native PowerShell:

```
Test-NetConnection -Port 800 -ComputerName 192.168.0.1 -InformationLevel Detailed
```

(Unfortunately this only works with PowerShell 4.0 or newer. To check your PowerShell version, type `$PSVersionTable`.)

PS: Note, these days there are some claims on the twittersphere that hint that this answer could be improved by mentioning "Test-Connection" from PowerShell Core, or the shortcut "tnc". See https://twitter.com/david_obrien/status/1214082339203993600 and help me edit this answer to improve it please!

---

(If you have a PSVersion < 4.0, you're out of luck. Check this table:

[image]

Even though you can upgrade your version of PowerShell  by installing the [Windows Management Framework 4.0](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=40855), it didn't do the trick for me, **Test-NetConnection** cmdlet is still not available).

Comment: This is a more reliable option than telnet, telnet would just hung not reporting anything while this reports that the port is available in my case.

Answer (score 45):

I did like that:

```
netstat -an | find "8080"
```

from telnet

```
telnet 192.168.100.132 8080
```

And just make sure that the firewall is off on that machine.

Comment: When I used that command i.e netstat -an | find "19345" , I didnt get any result. what does it mean? –

Comment: it means that this port is free

Comment: I get an error when I run `netstat -an | find "8080"` it says, `no such file named "8080"`

Answer (score 42):

On a Windows machine you can use [PortQry](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=17148) from Microsoft to check whether an application is already listening on a specific port using the following command:

```
portqry -n 11.22.33.44 -p tcp -e 80
```

Comment: Firewalled ports will generally appear as "FILTERED".

Comment: You could use this tool to check UDP port as well: `portqry -n 11.22.33.44 -p udp -e 19132`

Comment: https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=17148#Instructions

Answer (score 24):

If `telnet` is not available, download [PuTTY](http://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/~sgtatham/putty/download.html). It is a far superior Telnet, SSH, etc. client and will be useful in many situations, not just this one, especially if you are administering a server.

Comment: Yes, but not for pasting Forth code, say, with [AmForth](http://amforth.sourceforge.net/) (unless using PuTTY in combination with [Edit Overflow](http://pmortensen.eu/)).

Answer (score 16):

Use this if you want to see all the used and listening ports on a Windows server:

```
netstat -an |find /i "listening"
```

See all open, listening, established ports:

```
netstat -a
```

Answer (score 13):

Do you want a tool for doing it?  There is a website at http://www.canyouseeme.org/.  Otherwise, you need some other server to call you back to see if a port is open...

Answer (score 8):

On Windows Server you can use

```
netstat -an | where{$_.Contains("Yourport")}
```

Comment: Doesn't address the firewall issue in any way.

Comment: This works on powershell

Comment: Or do you mean "a Windows server"?

Answer (score 4):

[PsPing](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/psping) from Sysinternals is also very good.

Comment: Good tool. Example code would be: PsPing -n 20 -i 0 servername:port

Answer (score 4):

Another option is [tcping](http://www.elifulkerson.com/projects/tcping.php).

For example:

`tcping host port`

Answer (score 1):

Here is what worked for me:

- Open a command prompt
- Type `telnet`
- Microsoft Telnet>open <host name or IP address><space><port>

It will confirm whether the port is opened.

Answer (score 0):

Another utility that I found and is good and small as well, is [PortQry Command Line Port Scanner version 2.0](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=17148).

You can ping a server and a port and it will tell you the state of the port. There is a command-line utility and a UI for it.