# Wamp phpMyAdmin password issue

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin, wamp, mysql-error-1045

I'm new to working with web servers and need some assistance. I have downloaded the most recent Wamp server and did a bit of database design and querying. There was always a warning at the bottom of the admin page about setting up a password.

I tried doing this for the root user, but ended up doing something wrong. I no longer had permission to access phpmyadmin.

I removed the wamp program from my computer and re-installed Wamp again, but now when i try to log on to phpMyAdmin, i get this error

> MySQL said: #1045 - Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using
>   password: NO)

May someone please give me some assistance for how to overcome this.

Kind Regards

Answer (score 4):

[here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/resetting-permissions.html#resetting-permissions-windows) come the procedure to reset the root password, hope you would be able to solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

wamp : php + mysqladmin

I was facing the same problem.Before that phpmysqladmin was working properly in wamp environment.I had took my time.

In my case I tried to uninstall wamp couple of times and again install it but problem did not solve.

Here are some workarround:

1. check the port number 3306 and make it free.How to check if any port open or not use this

[How to determine if a port is open on a Windows server?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/273159/how-to-easy-determine-if-a-port-is-open-on-an-windows-server)

2. If it denies to log in and says access denied using password.Use this link:
   http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/resetting-permissions.html
3. If you can get access mysql for the first time when install wamp  go to mysql console and when ask password simply press enter.This will enable the option for phpmysqladmin to log in straighaway.
4. If you have some strange error like Plugin 'FEDERATED' is disabled which you dont have any clue then reset the mysql.search google with my.cnf and mysql reset
5. you can also use Xmapp instead of wamp!I guess that can help to reset the mysql automatically.

PS: reinstalling wamp will not harm your www data directory.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Personally I couldn't figure this out (Poor setup on wamp's part), but a quick fix is to edit config.inc.php and add:

```
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['AllowNoPassword'] = true;
```

Which allows you to use phpMyAdmin.