# How to remotely connect to ClearDB in an Azure Website?

Tags: mysql, remote-access, azure-web-app-service, cleardb

I have created a free Azure Website with Wordpress on it. A ClearDB mysql database was automatically created.
I want to remote connect to the DB using something like MySQL Workbench.
I used the credentials from the "View connection strings" in the azure portal dashboard, but there is an error connecting.

I read in some post that the db itself is hosted in azure cloud and thus can not be accessed. 
Have anyone managed to administrate a DB like this ?

Comment: I use SQL Buddy, installed on the same server, to manage my ClearDB database. http://sqlbuddy.com

Answer (score 1):

Mostly hoster **don't allow** an external connection with shared hostings.

When you use an outside client, your server has to [be configured](http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2010/08/allow-mysql-client-connection/) to allow this external connection.

### Firewall rules :

You must to set password before make this, for security improvement.

You must to **update firewall** and make rules to open the mysql port (3306) on the server that is running the mysql database.

### Set user IP :

Add an [user account](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/adding-users.html) or [replace ip address](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/rename-user.html).

Adding users :

```
CREATE USER 'monty'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'some_pass';
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'monty'@'localhost'
```

Replace ip address (be careful don't use this on the root user) :

```
RENAME USER 'user'@'ipaddress2' TO 'user'@'ipaddress2';
```

To allow all ip replace ip adress by `%`.

See more :

- [Security Guidelines](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/security-guidelines.html).
- [How to determine if a port is open on a Windows server?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/273159/how-to-determine-if-a-port-is-open-on-a-windows-server) or [www.portcheckers.com](http://www.portcheckers.com/).

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is possible to administer your ClearDB MySQL database in MySQL Workbench. I have several Azure Wordpress sites that I connect to just as you describe -- create the Azure site, view Connection Strings, type those credentials into MySQL Workbench, and voila. @Yaron, Can you be more specific about what you've tried and maybe we can troubleshoot from there?