# RabbitMQ - rabbitmq-users › No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it

Tags: php, connection, rabbitmq

I am new to RabbitMQ and I've been trying to follow the [tutorial](http://www.rabbitmq.com/tutorials/tutorial-one-php.html) of RabbitMQ.

I've copied the code for `send.php` and `receive.php`, but when I run the `send.php` and `receive.php` scripts, I get the following error:

> `Error Connecting to server(10061).:  No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it`

I've disabled my firewall and all my anti-virus programs, but I still get the same error.

The code of send.php and receive.php:

---

send.php

```
<?php

    require_once __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php';
    use PhpAmqpLib\Connection\AMQPConnection;
    use PhpAmqpLib\Message\AMQPMessage;

    $connection = new AMQPConnection('localhost', 5672, 'guest', 'guest');
    $channel = $connection->channel();


    $channel->queue_declare('hello', false, false, false, false);

    $msg = new AMQPMessage('Hello World!');
    $channel->basic_publish($msg, '', 'hello');

    echo " [x] Sent 'Hello World!'\n";

    $channel->close();
    $connection->close();

?>
```

---

receive.php

```
<?php

    require_once __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php';
    use PhpAmqpLib\Connection\AMQPConnection;

    $connection = new AMQPConnection('localhost', 5672, 'guest', 'guest');
    $channel = $connection->channel();


    $channel->queue_declare('hello', false, false, false, false);

    echo ' [*] Waiting for messages. To exit press CTRL+C', "\n";

    $callback = function($msg) {
         echo " [x] Received ", $msg->body, "\n";
    };

    $channel->basic_consume('hello', '', false, true, false, false, $callback);

    while(count($channel->callbacks)) {
        $channel->wait();
    }

    $channel->close();
    $connection->close();

?>
```

---

Can someone help me with this problem?
Thanks in advance

Comment: Did you test if the port 5672 isn't being used already?

Comment: I tested it, following this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/273159/how-to-determine-if-a-port-is-open-on-a-windows-server.

So when I executed the command "telnet localhost 5672", i couldn't make a connection. So I assume that port is still available right?

I also tried to change the portnumber in de php-files but I still get the same error as before.