# How do I use Xampp to localhost after installing apache?

Tags: php, mysql, apache, xampp, server

So I want to use Xampp to control my servers. I already installed Apache2 and now it orverrides localhost.

Whenever i put localhost/xampp/index.php it says OBJECT NOT FOUND.

How would I delete this Apache program, and strictly use Xampp on localhost?

I already tried to change the .conf file to Listen 8000 and when to http://localhost:8000/xampp/index.php

Comment: How about trying to type `localhost/index.php` instead. From me, it prompt xampp dashboard `http://localhost/dashboard/`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Steps:

   1. Open "XAMPP controll panel and run Apache and MySQL"
   2. create folder www inside `xampp\htdocs`, if you are on win propably        `C:\xampp\htdocs`, so now you have `C:\xampp\htdocs\www\`
   3. Create test.php inside `C:\xampp\htdocs\www\`, now you have `C:\xampp\htdocs\www\test.php`
   4. Put inside test this: `<?php echo 'php works fine.'; ?>`
   5. Run this script in browser on link "http://localhost/www/test.php" you will see "php works fine.".

DONE.

Answer (score 0):

Have you started apache by opening up Xampp control panel? If you didn't then it won't work. So open up Xampp control panel from the start menu and click on start where it says apache and then run http://localhost to see whether it works.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the :

> \xampp\apache\logs\error.log

This might give you an idea, why the XAMPP splash screen cannot be found.

Also, make sure you do not have any IIS or similar programs running, as they might have a conflict with the XAMPP.

You can also check if the port is open or not using the instructions given [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/273159/how-to-determine-if-a-port-is-open-on-a-windows-server)..

Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

I might be wrong, but it seems to me that everything on localhost is coming from htdocs, but you don't call it from htdocs in the URL.