# How to request an asp.net server hosted in an other pc

Tags: asp.net, windows, networking, webserver

I'm trying to request manually an asp.net distant server on the port 5000 in the same network. But it doesn't work properly, I have a "Connection_Timed_OUT" error.

I already tried to open the port 5000, from the windows firewall's advanced parameters but it doesn't work too.

**Edit :**
Below you can find my MVC Routing, but I'm not sure that where the problem is caused.

```
app.UseMvc(routes =>
        {
            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "default",
                template: "{controller}/{action}/{id?}");
        });
```

Comment: Could you show some code? What webserver? kestrel, iis? are you trying to reach a webapi?

Comment: Well it's a Kestrel server, my application use Asp.net core with MVC framework. When i tried to reach the server hosted on my computer, i wrote for example "localhost:5000/something" and the server gave me either a 404 error page or a MVC View.

Comment: Since you are trying to reach an other pc, you replaced the localhost by the ip or host right? perhaps it is a routing issue? you should post some code.

Comment: Yes I've done that, but It seems that maybe the port 5000 on the Internet Box which are connected the two PC, perhaps is closed ?

At the following my MVC Routing in the Configure method :
app.UseMvc(routes =>
            {
                routes.MapRoute(
                    name: "default",
                    template: "{controller}/{action}/{id?}");
            });

Comment: So the pc's are in the same LAN and subnet etc. and the firewall has port 5000 opened? so you can telnet it from the client pc? http://stackoverflow.com/a/273188/169714