# How to verify if port is open

Tags: java, .net, windows, networking

Could anyone please help me with steps how to verify if port is open/available to use.

Basically we have to verify in one of our server (windows) that 
7200 port is open for use.

we have one deployment coming up, and team have end point like htts://servername::7200/index.html

Comment: Try to connect.  If you get a reset or a timeout, it's not open.

Comment: please give me command line example

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Sockets: Discover port availability using Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/434718/sockets-discover-port-availability-using-java)

Comment: `telnet server.name 7200`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I determine if a port is open on a Windows server?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/273159/how-do-i-determine-if-a-port-is-open-on-a-windows-server)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are trying to use TCP(Transmission Control Protocol) port then run the `telnet host port` and see the result

1. `connection refused` means that nothing is running on that port
2. `accepted` means that something is running on that port
3. `timeout` means that a firewall is blocking access